# I have an issue in saving individual Object, rather than saving all the objects in NSMangedObject stack ??

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am new to the IOS programming, currently learning core data, I went into running the code where i need to save only specific objects in core data. So how can i do that?

According to the scenario, i have data from server as well as local storage (core data), but when user close the app (went to background) I want to store the data in the server(if net available) if not then in the local storage (but selected only - means specific data should be stored, there are objects which came from online server which i dont want to store on local).

Please let me know any solution if possible.

Regards
Nisar Ahmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to achieve this:

1. Iterate through inserted and updated objects and revert those you do not wont to save. Inserted objects should be deleted, updated should be refreshed:

   ```
   for (NSManagedObject* obj in [self.managedObjectContext insertedObjects]) {
       if (/*Shouldn't be saved*/) {
           [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:obj];
       }
   }

   for (NSManagedObject* obj in [self.managedObjectContext updatedObjects]) {
       if (/*Shouldn't be saved*/) {
           [self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:obj mergeChanges:NO];
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create separate managed object context. Recreate objects that you want to save in new context and then save it.

   ```
   NSManagedObjectContext* newContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
   [newContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self.managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator]];
   for (NSManagedObject* obj in objectsWantToSave) {
       NSEntityDescription* entity = [obj entity];
       NSDictionary* valuesByKeys = [obj dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[[entity attributesByName] allKeys]];
       NSManagedObject* objCopy = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:newContext];
       [objCopy setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:valuesByKeys];
   }
   [newContext save:NULL];
   ```

The second approach is better for my opinion.

Comment: Bro i also thought for the second approach, but i hope this will be against the apple guidelines, and the application can be rejected on that basis ? so any other solution instead of this (separated NSManagedObjectContext, or Separate Business Object)

Thanks

Comment: It is common practice. I've used it in many projects. I've never heard that app was rejected by this reason.

Comment: Thanks Bro, i will consider it in my mind, but is there any other approach except that ?? i really liked your both ideas ?? but also want some other ideas on this issue ?? I hope there could be any other solution rather than creating new NSManagedObjectContext ?
Regards

Comment: I do not think you will see another approach here. But any way good luck.

Comment: Thanks :) Mark Kryzhanouski

Comment: Thanks, I hope I got my answer, your 2nd approach is really a good apporoach, I checked it against the apple guidelines and found no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into UIManagedDocument - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIManagedDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html

It takes care of a lot of the boilerplate involved in using core data.

Comment: I already have gone through this reference, but didn't got my question answered, thats why i thought to put here, to get best solution. Thanks